# Android NDK link external so Error. java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc.so.6" not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

This is cmake file.

```
add_library( md
        SHARED
        IMPORTED )

set_target_properties( # Specifies the target library.
        md
        # Specifies the parameter you want to define.
        PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
        # Provides the path to the library you want to import.
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/jniLibs/${CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI}/libmd.so)

target_include_directories(
        jnitest
        PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
        jnitest
        md

        # Links the target library to the log library
        # included in the NDK.
        ${log-lib}
        )
```

How to solve the problem.
"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: library "libc.so.6" not found"

Comment: Where did you get this `libmd.so` file from? DId you build it yourself? (how?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is not GNU. libc.so.6 is the glibc library. You need to build `libmd.so` with the NDK.